# Writing an expression for a change in angular velocity of an angle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, mathematical-physics

[image]

Let $AB$ is rotating at $\omega_{AB}=4$ rad/s. Find $\omega_{CD}$ when $\theta=\pi/6$.

So the first thing I did was wrote an express for $CD$ call it $r$. $\phi$ is Angle $CAB$ for reference.

By law of sines I have that $r=\dfrac{0.3\sin \phi}{\sin \theta}$

Since $\Delta ABC $ is a right triangle, $r=0.6\cos \theta$ Taking derivative, and equating to each other I find that $\omega_{CD}$ is $\dfrac{0.3\cos \phi\cdot \omega_{AB}}{r\cos \theta - 0.6(\sin \theta)^2}$

For some reason this isn't the answer. Did I use the wrong relationship?

Comment: Does $AB = 300mm$?

Comment: This is a general suggestion, not specific to this question, but something which will help you in the future: generally, you want to manipulate the equations and get to the answers *before* you plug in the numbers. In other words, do all the algebra first and only then plug the numbers in.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. However, 0.3 and 0.6 are just constants so they don't effect the algebra much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sine law you get:

$$
\frac { AB }{ \sin { \theta  }  } \quad =\quad \frac { AC }{ \sin { (\pi -(\theta +\phi )) }  } \\ \frac { AB }{ \sin { \theta  }  } \quad =\quad \frac { AC }{ \sin { \left( \theta +\phi  \right)  }  } \\ \sin { \theta  } \quad =\quad \frac { AB }{ AC } \sin { \left( \theta +\phi  \right)  } \\ \frac { d }{ dt } \sin { \theta  } \quad =\quad \frac { AB }{ AC } \frac { d }{ dt } \sin { \left( \theta +\phi  \right)  } \\ \frac { d\theta  }{ dt } \cos { \theta  } \quad =\quad \frac { AB }{ AC } \left( \frac { d\theta  }{ dt } +\frac { d\phi  }{ dt }  \right) \cos { \left( \theta +\phi  \right)  } \\ { \omega  }_{ CD }\cos { \theta  } \quad =\quad \frac { AB }{ AC } \left( { \omega  }_{ CD }+\omega  \right) \sqrt { 1-\sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( \theta +\phi  \right)  }  } \\ { \omega  }_{ CD }\cos { \theta  } \quad -\frac { AB }{ AC } { \omega  }_{ CD }\sqrt { 1-\sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( \theta +\phi  \right)  }  } \quad =\quad \frac { AB }{ AC } \omega \sqrt { 1-\sin ^{ 2 }{ (\theta +\phi ) }  } \\ { \omega  }_{ CD }\left( \cos { \theta  } -\frac { AB }{ AC } \sqrt { 1-{ \left( \frac { AC }{ AB } \sin { \theta  }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  \right) \quad =\quad \frac { AB }{ AC } \omega \sqrt { 1-{ \left( \frac { AC }{ AB } \sin { \theta  }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } \\ { \omega  }_{ CD }\quad =\quad \frac { \frac { AB }{ AC } \omega \sqrt { 1-{ \left( \frac { AC }{ AB } \sin { \theta  }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }{ \cos { \theta  } -\frac { AB }{ AC } \sqrt { 1-{ \left( \frac { AC }{ AB } \sin { \theta  }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  } 
$$

Now plug in the constants and the value of $\theta$ and you'll get the answer

Comment: @adam now this answer is corrected, note that at $\theta = pi/6\quad {\omega}_{CD} = 0$ but it's not the case for another $\theta$, getting $0$ is normal and DOESN'T imply that ${\omega}_{CD$, but simply that the angle attained its maximum value